# Give an example of a function that fails to satisfy the Lipschitz condition at a point of continuity.

Tags: real-analysis

Definition of the Lipschitz condition:

A function $f: (a,b)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ satisfies the Lipschitz condition at $x\in(a,b)$ iff there is $M>0$ and $\epsilon>0$ such that $\lvert x - y\rvert < \epsilon$ and $y\in(a,b)$ imply that $\lvert f(x) - f(y)\rvert\le M\lvert x-y\rvert$.

Actual question:

Give an example of a function that fails to satisfy the Lipschitz condition at a point of continuity. If $f$ is differentiable at $x$, prove that $f$ satisfies the Lipschitz condition at $x$.

Comment: I am curious as to why you accepted an answer that does not answer your question, even though there are two other answers that do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $f(x)=x^{1/3}$ at $x=0$.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**: If $f$ is differentiable at $x$, then the quantity

$$\left| \frac{f(y) - f(x)}{y - x} \right|$$

must be bounded in a neighborhood of $x$ (why?). How does this relate to the Lipschitz condition?

---

For the other question, consider a function with a vertical tangent line, such as $x^{1/3}$.

Answer (score 2):

$f(x) = \sqrt{|x|}$ at $x=0$.

Suppose $f$ is differentiable at $x$, then $\lim_{y \to x} \frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y} = f'(x)$. By continuity of the absolute value we have $\lim_{y \to x} |\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}| = |f'(x)|$.

Let $L=\max(1,2|f'(x)|)$, by definition of the limit, there is some $\delta>0$ such that if $|y-x| < \delta$, then $|\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}| \le L$. In other words, $| f(x)-f(y) | \le L|x-y|$ for $|x-y| < \delta$.